# How to access options.php on form submit when the user role is contributor?

Tags: wordpress

I creating one wordpress plugin where I want to update options.

I used below code

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
```

But When I submit this form I got error

```
 Cheatin’ uh?
```

Here I have logged in as contributor.So How to submit this form when user is contributor? I want to access only this file when user is contributor.

Comment: use `update_option()` for this...why you access directly options.php

Comment: thanks... but I want to update one field from both admin and contributors side... so I am trying to use same form but it won't works for me.